# Can I open file for edit in default app and get signal/result after editing?

Tags: android

Can I open file for edit in default app and get signal/result after editing?
I know about intents but how I get signal about that edit canceled from another program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I open file for edit in default app and get signal/result after editing?

Not generally. You are welcome to contact the developers of editor apps and see if they have some API that would allow third-party apps, like yours, to request that app allow the user to edit some content, then let you know when the editing is complete.